# Making multiple mysql calls using JS promise in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

**GOAL:**

I am trying to make multiple SQL queries using the "mysql" module in Node.js such that the result of one query is used as input in the next statement.

```
sql1 = SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=? // get user id from email
val1 = test@email.com

sql2 = SELECT something FROM profiles WHERE user_id=?
val2 = user_id // result of sql1
```

**APPROACH:**

I am using a JS "promise" to achieve this:

```
var run_query = function(conn,sql){

return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){

    conn.query(sql, val, function(err, res) {

        if(err) reject(err);
        else    fulfill(res);

    });

});

}

var conn = db.config(mysql);

run_query(conn,[ 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=?' , ['test@email.com'] ]).then(function(result){

  console.log(result.id); // result of 1st query

  return run_query(conn,[ 'SELECT something FROM profiles WHERE user_id=?' , [result.id] ]);

}).then(function(result){

    console.log(result.something); // result of 2nd query 

}).catch(function(err){

    console.log('there was an error', err);

});

conn.end();
```

**ISSUE:**

The 1st query returns the correct result, but the second query throws the following error from the mysql module:

```
Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.
~blah blah blah~
code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT', fatal: false
```

**MY ATTEMPTS TO RESOLVE:**

I believe this has something to do with multiple calls being made while the connection is open and **conn.end();** being called at the very end. I moved it around a bit but that didnt work.

I tried turning on multiple statement for the mysql module

```
var conn = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```

..but that didnt work either.

How does one use the mysql node module with a JS promise structure?

Comment: You might want to use something like [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/) that supports promises out of the box rather than hacking together your own wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using promise but the promise code is synchronse and outer code is asynchronse . so conn.end run before your second query.

Use `conn.end` inside second .then block like this
and remove outer `conn.end`:

```
var conn = db.config(mysql);

run_query(conn,[ 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=?' ,
['test@email.com'] ]).then(function(result){

 console.log(result.id); // result of 1st query

 return run_query(conn,[ 'SELECT something FROM profiles WHERE
user_id=?' , [result.id] ]);

}).then(function(result){

   console.log(result.something); // result of 2nd query 
    conn.end();
}).catch(function(err){

   console.log('there was an error', err);

});
```

Comment: Translation: "Hey, MySQL, can you do this query, plus a bunch of other stuff depending on that? Oh, and while you're doing that, can you close the connection right now?" You're pulling the plug on this thing before it's finished.

Answer (score 1):

Promises explicitly is used to write cleaner code but you are doing quite the opposite.

What Himanshu said is right your `conn.end()` is executed first. Given your use case I'd suggest you to use `Async` Module [Click Here](https://github.com/caolan/async). Go through features available once.

I think `Async.series` will server you right although there are multiple async features that can help your case, notably, queue.

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
     //Your First SQL Query based on response send success or failure callback
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback) {
     //Your Second SQL Query based on response send success or failure callback
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results) {
    //listen to results from your codes and put some logic based on what you want and close the connection here
conn.close();
});
```

Doubt : Why do you want to execute them one by one?

Comment: Gandalf the White , his promise syntax is right . No need to use async.series ,he can do by promise . You can say async.series is another approach to do this work.

Comment: the code looks far from clean and I never said his syntax is wrong? Read again. And, people do suggest better ways to solve a problem on SO. I hope you are aware about that.

Comment: why is the code not clean? I have a promise function and a .then chain. I have implemented an async version like you posted prior to this but the point is to use the result of one query as the input in another. doing this asynchronously would not make sense since you wouldnt have the first result reliably available

Comment: @yevg everyone has their opinion I believe, I would rather choose aysnc for such work. From the code written above I cannot see that you are using values from one part for another one. If  you want that you can use waterfall flow from async module. Async module was made to solve anti patterns man.